# Toggle class in jQuery switching rather than appending

Tags: jquery, html, toggleclass

I'm trying to add a class to an element on click called 'activetab'.
How can I make it so if you click tab2, you add the class, but then if you click tab3 it takes it off tab 2 and onto tab 3 and so on. At the minute it just appends it.

```
$(".tab2").click(function () {
    $(".tab2").addClass("activetab");
});

$(".tab3").click(function () {
    $(".tab3").addClass("activetab");
});

$(".tab4").click(function () {
    $(".tab4").addClass("activetab");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove the class. Also, all the handler can be combined to make a single handler which will add the `activetab` class to the clicked tab and remove it from other tabs.

```
// Bind click event on all the tabs
$(".tab2, .tab3, .tab4").click(function () {
    // Remove class from other tab
    $(".activetab").removeClass('activetab');

    // Add class to the current clicked tab
    $(this).addClass("activetab");
});
```